# Flask - best way to pass large JSON object to template

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, stream

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a large JSON object constructed from a list of list of about 500000+ entries to a template.  The current way I'm doing it worked for smaller objects:

```
return render_template('/dataprocessing.html', data=json.dumps(result))
```

Where *data=json.dumps(result)* is how I pass the large JSON object to the template. However, the size of this object stored in the client greatly slows down my application. I also know that there is another way to pass it through cookies, but that is worse than this method and won't work for larger sizes.

### Would I be able to read this JSON object in my template more efficiently if i wrote it to a file and read from it?

### Or would streaming be a better way of doing this? (I'm not really familiar with this way)

Comment: Your code passes a JSON formatted _string_ to the template renderer, not a JSON _object_, because `json.dumps()` returns a JSON formatted string. It would help if you explained what the template does with all of that data. You might be able to use paging or some other strategy to display the data in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

It's no surprise that trying to pass a half-million objects through a view and into a template (and then over the wire (and then into the browser)) might slow down your application.

This an invitation to rethink what you're doing, and how important the user experience is. Do you need all of the objects at once? Is this a situation where you can stream that data out into chunks (e.g., to continue to grow a table as the user scrolls)? Are some objects more 'important' than other objects? Can you display key objects first, and then add as the user watches or drills in?

Much depends on what you're trying to do.